# Not able to install Oracle 21c DB on windows machine

Tags: database, installation, listener, tnsnames, oracle21c

[All error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjQCe.png)

Configuring Oracle XE listener...
Oracle XE listener configured successfully.
Configuring Oracle XE database...
7% complete
 û
8% complete
 û

[FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

29% complete
100% complete
[FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

û
7% complete
[FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

29
0% complete
[FATAL] ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

29
Performing post XE database creation actions...
Post XE database creation actions completed.
{IDS_OracleConfigDlg_DatabaseConfigFailedMsg} An error occurred while configuring Oracle XE database. Check the logs at C:\app\blues\product\21c\cfgtoollogs\dbca and try again.

I followed oracle documentation for setup still face same issue, need solution to install this version of DB on my machine without any issues.

Comment: What did the installer log file say happened? What version of Windows are you running? Did you run the install as an administrator?